# What is a Professional way to customize Fan Page on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

What is more professional way to customize the Fan page on facebook, on is staticFBML - seems pretty newbie way ... ?

Answer (score 0):

It's what most corporate customizers use. Just because it's easy doesn't mean it's bad.

Comment: nice answer, I am looking for details on if it is bad or not , but still some arguments would be very helpful

Comment: I'm curious: Are you afraid of being judged for using it or something? Are you afraid of lack of expandability or features? What's the holdup?